# Core dump while staring a Jetpack Compose Application

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am using Kubuntu 20.10 and tried to run examples of the project [Compose-jb](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb) with Intellij Ultimate 2020.3. After the built with gradle I have tried to run the example, but everytime the following error occurs:

```
 Task :run FAILED

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdcc01cad88, pid=6176, tid=6212

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (14.0.2+12) (build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-1)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libGLX.so.0+0x6d88]  glXCreateContext+0x18
```

I have tried this with different Jetpack Compose Projects and different versions of the JDK, but the same error occures everytime.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from the Flatpack Version of Intellij to the Version installed from the Jetbrains Toolbox solves the problem.